# Do UK residents have to fill out landing cards?

Tags: uk, uk-residents, customs-and-immigration

I'm from a non-EEA country and I previously filled out landing cards to enter the UK. Now I'm a UK resident with a Tier 2 visa. Do I still have to fill out those cards?

Home Office already know the following information about me. Actually they know all except 'contact address' even if I'm not a resident.

- Family name
- First name
- Sex
- Town and country of birth
- Nationality
- Contact address in the UK (in full)
- Passport no

This field is not applicable. The officer filled in this herself when I entered with the 'entry clearance' vignette, but I don't remember what she wrote.

- Length of stay in the UK

Maybe the following fields provide some information for statistics, however they must already have the passenger lists.

- Port of last departure
- Arrival flight

Comment: I am not 100% sure but my understanding is that everyone who isn't an EU/EEA national must fill in the landing card, even if they are a UK resident, at least until they finally get rid of them.

Comment: For the record, I seemed to remember there were plans to scrap landing cards sometime last year. Clearly it fell through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@MichaelHampton is correct. While a Tier 2 visa allows you to live and work in the UK, as a non-EEA national you would still need to complete a landing card. However, there is an exception you might consider, the [Registered Traveller](https://www.gov.uk/registered-traveller/eligibility), should you be eligible.

> [**Entering the UK**](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/at-border-control)
>
> **You’re from a non-EEA country**
>
> Your carrier will give you a landing card - fill this in before you arrive at border control.
>
> Your passport, landing card (and visa if you have one) will be checked.
>
> You’ll usually be asked why you’re coming to the UK.
>
> Keep documents that show the reason for your visit in your hand luggage, so you can show them if asked, for example your travel itinerary, work permit or university letter.
>
> **Registered Travellers**
>
> If you’ve joined the [Registered Traveller service](https://www.gov.uk/registered-traveller), you can use the:
>
> - UK/EEA channels
> - automatic ePassport gates if your passport has a ‘chip’
>
> You will not need a landing card at [some UK airports](https://www.gov.uk/registered-traveller/where-you-can-use-registered-traveller).
>
> **Travelling with a UK biometric visa**
>
> You’ll have a biometric visa if your fingerprints were taken when you applied.
>
> Your fingerprints will be checked at border control - they’ll be checked against the ones stored on your visa document.

Comment: then again, for the occasional traveler it's often more of a hassle and cost factor to sign up for such services than to fill out the cards.